# Problem with shapes of experimental Tensorflow dataset

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, dataset, reshape

I am trying to store numpy arrays in a Tensorflow dataset. The model fits correctly when using the numpy arrays as train and test data but not when I *store the numpy arrays in a single Tensorflow dataset*. The problem is with the dimensions of the dataset. Something is wrong even though shapes seem OK at first sight.

After trying multiple things to reshape my Tensorflow dataset, I am still unable to get it working. My code is the following:

```
train_x.shape 
Out[54]: (7200, 40)
train_y.shape
Out[55]: (7200,)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
print(dataset)
Out[56]: <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((40,), ()), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=256)

    sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
        logits.get_shape()))
    ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (40, 1351)).
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398491/valueerror-shape-mismatch-the-shape-of-labels-received-15-should-equal-th) but I am sure it doesn't apply here. I must use sparse_categorical_crossentropy. I am inspiring myself from [this example](https://gist.github.com/maxim5/c35ef2238ae708ccb0e55624e9e0252b) where I want to store the train and test data in a Tensorflow dataset. I also want to store the arrays in a dataset as I will have to use it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `batch_size` with `model.fit()` when using a `tf.data.Dataset`. Instead use `tf.data.Dataset.batch()`. You'll have to change your code as follows for it to work.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Some toy data
train_x = np.random.normal(size=(7200, 40))
train_y = np.random.choice([0,1,2], size=(7200))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_x,train_y))
dataset = dataset.batch(256)

#### - Define your model here - ####

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS)
```