# Tensorflow Shape mismatch

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to build a multi-output model.
I'm encountering the error

```
ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (3600000,))
should equal the shape of logits except
for the last dimension (received (10, 360000)).
```

I have to make output 360000 datas that has 25 classes.
And my input has range [0, 1].
My input is such as

```
[x1, x2, x3, ....., x1080000]
```

and my output is such as

```
[y1, y2, y3, ....., y360000]
```

For addition, the shape my input dataset is (66, 1080000), and my output dataset is (66, 360000)

And this is my full code.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
inputs = Input(shape=(1080000, ))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
outputs =  Dense(360000, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='test')
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
             metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=10, epochs=50)
```

I don't understand why labels aren't same with logits.
How can I prevent the error?

Comment: What are the 360000 data? I mean, do you have 360,000 different classes which you want to predict? Are they one-hot encoded?

Comment: i have to print 360000 datas that has 25 classes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to your loss function. What happens if you try `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`?

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

This answer adds more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402308/177154

Comment: It does work, but loss and accuracy doesn't work.